# Woocommerce REST API - Invalid parameter(s): attributes [rest_invalid_param]

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I am using `Automattic\WooCommerce` to create a plugin for my website. The idea is to create a variable product with some information and then, create the variations of the product.

Creating the product is working fine

`POST` to `/products` has not been any problem

But when I try to create the variations, I keep getting error messages. The last one is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException: Error: Invalid parameter(s): attributes [rest_invalid_param]
```

I am sending this array to

`POST` to `/products/$id/variations`, but it results in the error described above. I don't know which is the invalid param.

```
{
    "date_created": "2017-10-21",
    "description": "Some random description",
    "sku": "",
    "price": "0",
    "visible": true,
    "purchasable": true,
    "virtual": true,
    "manage_stock": false,
    "stock_quantity": 1,
    "in_stock": true,
    "date_on_sale_from": "2017-10-21",
    "date_on_sale_to": "2017-10-24",
    "attributes": {
        "id": 0,
        "option": "No certificate"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

your attributes parameter is invalid.
You should pass the attributes like following :

```
{
"date_created": "2017-10-21",
"description": "Some random description",
"sku": "",
"price": "0",
"visible": true,
"purchasable": true,
"virtual": true,
"manage_stock": false,
"stock_quantity": 1,
"in_stock": true,
"date_on_sale_from": "2017-10-21",
"date_on_sale_to": "2017-10-24",
"attributes": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "option": "No certificate"
    }
  ]
}
```

you can see the documentation of the woocommerce rest API for the variation.

Visit https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product-variation

Answer (score 1):

I going to write just if somebody fall here.

The first step you have to do is create your variable product variable whit all data you need.

```
$prod = [
        'name'              => 'Name the product'
        'type'              => 'variable', 
        'status'            => 'draft',
        'sku'               => 'valid-sku',
        'regular_price'     => '120',
        'manage_stock'      => 'false',
        'stock_status'      => 'instock',
        'tax_status'        => 'taxable',
        'categories' => [[id => 1]],
        'attributes' => [
            [ //Brand
                'id'    => 5,
                'position' => 1,
                'visible' => false,
                'variation' => false,
                'options'=> ['Brand you want'],
                'name'  => 'Marca'
            ],[ //Gender
                'id'    => 3,
                'position' => 2,
                'visible' => false,
                'variation' => false,
                'options'=> 'male',
                'name'  => 'Gender'
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Make the post

```
$wooProd = $woocommerce->post('products', $prod);
```

And then create the variation information

```
$variation = ['create' => [
        'sku'           => $variation['SKU'],
                'manage_stock'  => 'true',
                'stock_quantity'=> 'SKU-VARIATON',
                'regular_price' => '150',
                'sale_price'    => '120',
                'attributes'    => [[ //Brand
                        'id'    => 5,
                        'position' => 1,
                        'visible' => false,
                        'variation' => false,
                        'options'=> ['Brand you want'],
                        'name'  => 'Brand',
                    ],[ //Gender
                        'id'    => 3,
                        'position' => 2,
                        'visible' => false,
                        'variation' => false,
                        'options'=> 'Male',
                        'name'  => 'Gender',
                    ]
                ]
    ]];
```

And make the post

```
$woocommerce->post( "products/$wooProd->id/variations/batch", $variation_data );
```

This is everything. Maybe you want to make a For to make the variation data mor complex or something like that..

I hope this work or make some light in the path :)
Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that attribute values which are numbers , to be passed as a string. It's stupid but if you pass attribute values as numbers and not strings it shoots an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
/products/$id/variations
```

to:

```
/products/{id}/variations
```

Then pass the `$id` as parameter in your function.